# Медиафайлы отсутствуют после импорта в блог

Tags: wordpress

Импортирую обычным xml файлом записи и все медиа в блог. Однако записи перенеслись а медиа нет. То пустые квадраты, нет фото, то фотки отображаются в блоге но ведут по ссылке на старый адрес блога. В итоге медиа никак не могу перенести. в чем может быть тут проблема?

Comment: может быть.. в хостинге

Comment: может. но импортировал недавно на другой сайт этого же хостинга и было все гуд

Comment: Ну ты ж спросил - в чём МОЖЕТ быть проблема.. см https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82/

Comment: узнал у хостинга. все нормально. попробовал он какую то настройку изменить но это не помогло. пришлось вручную исправить ссылки в записях на фото, удалить лишние миниатюры и использовать плагин Media from FTP чтобы зарегистрировать медиа в админке. получилось!